# Heap tree height vs BST height

Tags: logging, properties, height, heap, binary-search-tree

I was asked in a course the following question. "(A) Given a heap-tree with 12 elements, what's it's height? (B) If it was a BST (Binary-Search-Tree), which would be it's height?"

Now, I understand that heap is a complete binary tree and according to GFG: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/height-complete-binary-tree-heap-n-nodes/, the answer to (A) is: 3

I have found in a book that the height of a binary tree is: **log2(N + 1)**, so If I replace this formula in the code above, the answer becomes: 4. Is this the answer to (B)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A binary heap with 12 elements will have four levels, for example:

```
         1
    2         3
  4   5     6   7
 8 9 A B  C
```

. If you call that a height of 3, then your answer is correct.

A binary search tree with 12 elements can have from 4 to 12 levels, depending on whether it's balanced. For example, the heap above is a valid BST, as is this:

```
        4
    2        8
  1   3   6     A
         5 7   9 B
                  C
```

And this:

```
1
 2
  3
   4
    5
     6
      7
       8
        9
         A
          B
           C
```

Comment: Took me a little while to understand that a BST may be totally unbalanced given on how root is inserted. Thank you for your answer! :)